# How to gnuplot from data file using mac terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I installed gnuplot on OSX Lion. However, I am having difficulty plotting data from a file using the plot command, I get this error prompt,

```
plot /Users/kukiyuki/Desktop/gnuplottest/test.txt u 1:2 w l
     ^
invalid expression
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try using quotes, eg:

```
gnuplot> plot "./data.txt" #it appears a graph
```

whereas without quotes your error appears:

```
gnuplot> plot ./data.txt
              ^
         invalid expression
```